# What does the Author property mean in the query service?

Tags: search, caml-query, enterprise-search

I'm using the query search services of SharePoint and I'm not able to find in the MS documentation if the Author property matches the Created By, Modified By or both (or something else :)).

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SharePoint fields have display names and internal names. Created By or Modified By are display names of fields. Internal names are used when creating queries. `Author` is the internal name of `Created By` field and `Editor` is the internal name of `Modified By` field.

**UPDATE**

One way to check the internal name of a field from SharePoint UI is to go into List Settings and Click on the Column Name e.g. `Modified By` in Columns section. Observe the Url in the browser. It will be something like this:

```
http://aissp2013:111/_layouts/15/FldEditEx.aspx?List=%7B98089921%2D96C3%2D4B8C%2DB5D0%2D593360EFD1DA%7D&Field=Editor
```

At the end of the url is `&Field=Editor` which gives the internal name of the column.

However, as your question is regarding Search Service, this is how you should try to set up your `CreatedBy` and `ModifiedBy` managed properties in Search:

Go to Search service application in SharePoint Central administration site and click on Search Schema. Check the crawled properties of `Author` and `Created By` managed properties. You may need to add `Office:4(Text)` crawled property to `Created By` managed property. This is what I had to do long time before in [SharePoint 2010](http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.com/2012/02/search-using-createdby-metadata.html). Similarly search the managed property `EditorOWSUSER` and notice the crawled property it is mapped to and then add that crawled property to `ModifiedBy` managed property.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply!. BTW, where did you get that information? I tried using Editor instead of Author in my query and I'm getting no results in SP2013 even though there are documents modified by the person I'm using. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @Omer, see my updated answer

Comment: Hey! I believe your answer is the most complete one. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, Author is the Created By. Not sure why they named it the way they did.

Comment: As I know Author is internal name of Created By field. That is why they named it like this.

Comment: @Carl, this should be a comment - not a second answer.

Comment: @MaxMelcher The original question asks "if the Author property matches the Created By"

Answer (score 0):

`Author` is the internal name for a `Created By` field and the Managed Property named `Author` is mapped to the Crawled Property `Author`.

It means Search Crawler extracts `Created By` field values and Search Index stores them in `Author` Managed Property

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply!. BTW, are you get this information from an official MS documentation? if so, could you please share the source?

Comment: Hey, unfortunately I wasnt able to find any official information about managed properties mapping.  But you could always check yourself managed property mapping in search settings, in fact this is how I verified it